# How to http into application installed on minikube inside Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, minikube

I have installed minikube on AWS ec2 instance and there I have deployed my application microservices. I have exposed one microservice to the outside world on port 30020 using NodePort configuration.
My microservices are running fine, but I do not know how to access my microservice from my laptop browser.
I have tried the following -

1) using public ip address of my ec2 instance. But this is not working as my application is inside a minikube cluster and this minikube cluster has its own ip address.

2) I tried using minikube ip to access my application but this is also not working on my laptop browser.

Comment: are you able to access the application from within the EC2 instance using the <node _ip>:30020 ?

Comment: have you opened that port on the security group?